# lightning icon size is changing

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds, slds-grid, icon

I am using `lightning-icon` in a tile.But for a sentence ,the size of the icon is changing.(icon is not in round shape).

```
[![<template>
    <div class="values">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-text-align_left">
           <lightning-icon icon-name="action:approval" size="xx-small"> 
           </lightning-icon>
           <div class="custom">Pending approval from Organisation</div>
       </div>
       <div class="slds-grid slds-text-align_left">
          <lightning-icon icon-name="action:close" size="xx-small"> 
          </lightning-icon>
          <div class="custom-class">Withdraw</div>
      </div>
       -------------------------------------
       -------------------------------------
   </div>
</template>
```

Could someone help?Thanks in Advance

Screenshot[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful, plus the surrounding code for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the icon inside a container of some sort. Without this wrapper element, `slds-grid` will stretch the icon to fit the size of the cell.

```
<lightning-tile label="Lightning component team" href="/path/to/somewhere">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-text-align_left slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-12">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="action:approval" size="xx-small">
            </lightning-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="custom slds-size_11-of-12">Pending approval from Organisation</div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-12">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="action:close" size="xx-small">
            </lightning-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="custom slds-size_11-of-12 custom-class">Withdraw</div>
    </div>
</lightning-tile>
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/NfhaMYFMCj2D1LpqUaxh/src/app.html?p=stories).